# Run commands as administrator from cygwin / mintty

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, cmake, uac, mintty

I am running mintty on cygwin in Windows 7. I have mintty.exe set to always "Run as administrator". I am trying to run cmake from within mintty to build a Visual Studio 11 solution.

However, when cmake tries to do a test compile it fails, because **CL.exe** does not have enough privileges to run. I have set **cmake.exe**, **devenv.exe**, and all **CL.exe** I could find on my disk to always "Run as administrator", but it didn't help.

When I run the same cmake command from a Windows command line launched with administrator privileges it succeeds. This tells me that cmake and CL executables are set up correctly, but somehow calling them from mintty / cygwin launches them without the administrator rights.

Any ideas on how I can set up cygwin to launch all external executables using the "Run as administrator" setting?

**EDIT:** Some more information about the combinations I tried and their results.

**Running cmake (non-admin) in cmd (non-admin)** produces `Could not COPY_FILE` errors described [here](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-January/034317.html). The proposed solution is to run `devenv.exe` and `cmake.exe` as admin.

**Running cmake (non-admin) in cmd (admin)** works. I get the admin prompt when the command line is opened, no prompt to run cmake.

**Running cmake (admin) in cmd (non-admin)** works. A new command window pops up and I get the admin prompt to run cmake.

**Running cmake (admin) in cmd (admin)** works. I get the admin prompt when the command line is opened, no prompt to run cmake.

**Running cmake (non-admin) in mintty (non-admin)** produces the same result as non-admin cmake in non-admin cmd.

**Running cmake (non-admin) in mintty (admin)** produces a different error (described [here](http://blog.ashodnakashian.com/2012/01/building-webkit-on-windows-7-with-vs2010/#windows-7-uac)) which basically boils down to `cl.exe` not running as administrator. I get the admin prompt when starting mintty.

**Running cmake (admin) in mintty (non-admin)** results in `Permission denied` for the cmake executable.

**Running cmake (admin) in mintty (admin)** produces the same result as non-admin cmake and admin mintty.

Comment: You can post your Edit 2 as the answer to your own question. Nevertheless the behavior is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> OK, I managed to "solve" it. The problem was I was always running Visual Studio 11 as administrator. (I did that so I could attach the debugger to a running process with admin privileges, which I need for work.) When VS11 was always run as admin, it required `cmake` to be run as admin, which in turn required `cmd` or `mintty` to be run as admin.
>
> Now why this worked with `cmd` and not `mintty`, i.e. why the admin escalation didn't get all the way through to `cl.exe` I don't know.